# How to thow error to parent promise from child promise in pg-promises

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, knex.js, pg-promise

I have two tables "A" and "B". I want to create a row in table "B" which contains primary key of table "A" and this whole operation should be atomic.

```
function test(data, res) {
    let query1 = knex.insert([data], "id").into("A").toString();
    let query2 = "";
    db.tx(function (t) {
        return this.batch([
            t.one(query1).then(function (id) {
                query2 = knex.insert({A_id:id, x:x, y:y}).into("B").toString();
                t.none(query2).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);  // want to pass this error to next catch block
                });
            })
        ]);
    }).then(function () {
        console.log("success");
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Here whenever an error come at nested promise i want to reject parent promise and pass that error to parent promise.

Comment: Unless you are doing anything constructive in the child `catch()` just remove it and the parent catch will fire  so long as you keep returning promises but you also need to return `t.none` inside `t.one`

Comment: @charlietfl I tried it but not working getting error "Unhandled promise rejection".

Comment: There is absolutely no point in using `t.batch` in your transaction. And `pg-promise` has its own, and even more powerful support for generating inserts and updates, you do not need to use `knex` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise). It has all the right ingredients for writing very clean code:

```
function test(data) {
    db.tx(async t => {
        let b = await t.one('INSERT INTO B(col1, col2) VALUES(${prop1}, ${prop2}) RETURNING id', data);
        await t.none('INSERT INTO A(col1, col2) VALUES($1, $2)', ['bla', b.id]);
    })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('SUCCESS');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('ERROR:', error);
        });
}
```

You do not need to use `t.batch` in your example at all, and it is the best for using ES7 async.

And if you really want to generate inserts automatically, see the [helpers](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html) namespace, no need for a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working....had to return promise from child parent which is t.none() without catch()

Answer (score 0):

Which might be a common mistake (how I stumbled upon this answer) is that I just forgot an `await` in the child method.

Also make sure to use for loops when using await, as it won't work inside a foreach callback.

```
async function apiEndpoint() {
    return db.tx(async t => {
       insertItems(t, ['red', 'green', 'blue'])
    })
}

async function insertItems(t, colors){
   // Incorrect Loop - forEach don't work with await
   colors.forEach(color => await t.none(...)) 
   // Correct Loop
   for(let color of colors){
     // Incorrect usage - missing await
     t.none(...)
     // Correct usage with await
     await t.none('INSERT INTO item (color) VALUES ($1)', color);
     }
}
```